# Change OpenVPN client, can I use the same server configurations using scp?

Tags: openvpn, fedora, scp

I want to change my old FC 4 client to new Fedora 19 client, but I need to use all the same files on openvpn and IP address.

Can I use SCP command for copy all this configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it would certainly depend on the specifics of how your VPN is configured, a simple file copy should certainly work for most OpenVPN setups.

Comment: This^ And don't forget to copy the certificates/keys (or generate new ones).